# glTextImage2D is not returning desired outputs (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl-3

I'm new to openGL so I'm testing some things out based on the tutorials from learnopengl.com

I was learning about textures so I decided to try some things out. This is my code.

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

#include "Shader.h"

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 400;

int main()
{
// glfw: initialize and configure
// ------------------------------
glfwInit();
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // uncomment this statement to fix compilation on OS X
#endif
// glfw window creation
// --------------------
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
if (window == NULL)
{
std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
glfwTerminate();
return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

// glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
// ---------------------------------------
if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
{
std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
return -1;
}

// build and compile our shader zprogram
// ------------------------------------
Shader ourShader("DVDVertexShader.txt", "DVDFragmentShader.txt");

// set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
float vertices[] = {
// positions          // colors           // texture coords
0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
-0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // top left
};
unsigned int indices[] = {
0, 1, 3, // first triangle
1, 2, 3  // second triangle
};
unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// position attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
// color attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
// texture coord attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

// load and create a texture
// -------------------------
unsigned int texture;

// texture
// ---------
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
// set the texture wrapping parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
// set texture filtering parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
// load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
int width, height, nrChannels;

stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true); 

unsigned char *data = stbi_load("dvd_logo2.png", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);

std::cout << "width and height is " << width << ", " << height << std::endl;

if (data)
{
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
else
{
std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}
stbi_image_free(data);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
// render loop
// -----------

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
// input
// -----
processInput(window);

// render
// ------
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// render container
ourShader.use();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

// glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
glfwSwapBuffers(window);
glfwPollEvents();

}

// optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);

// glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Note that stb_image.h is a header file that allows us to load images from any format. It's an open source code that's available in github.

https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h

This is the Shader.h code just in case.

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <glad/glad.h>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Shader.h"

class Shader
{
public:
    unsigned int ID;
    // constructor generates the shader on the fly
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Shader(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath)
    {
        // 1. retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        std::ifstream vShaderFile;
        std::ifstream fShaderFile;
        // ensure ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
        vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        try
        {
            // open files
            std::cout << "vertexPath is " << vertexPath<<std::endl;
            std::cout << "fragmentPath is " << fragmentPath<<std::endl;
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
            fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
            std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
            // read file's buffer contents into streams
            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
            // close file handlers
            vShaderFile.close();
            fShaderFile.close();
            // convert stream into string
            vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
            fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
        }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
        }
        const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const char * fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
        // 2. compile shaders
        unsigned int vertex, fragment;
        int success;
        char infoLog[512];
        // vertex shader
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);
        checkCompileErrors(vertex, "VERTEX");
        // fragment Shader
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        checkCompileErrors(fragment, "FRAGMENT");
        // shader Program
        ID = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ID, vertex);
        glAttachShader(ID, fragment);
        glLinkProgram(ID);
        checkCompileErrors(ID, "PROGRAM");
        // delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessary
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);
    }
    // activate the shader
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void use()
    {
        glUseProgram(ID);
    }
    // utility uniform functions
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setBool(const std::string &name, bool value) const
    {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), (int)value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setInt(const std::string &name, int value) const
    {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setFloat(const std::string &name, float value) const
    {
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
    }

private:
    // utility function for checking shader compilation/linking errors.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void checkCompileErrors(unsigned int shader, std::string type)
    {
        int success;
        char infoLog[1024];
        if (type != "PROGRAM")
        {
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
            if (!success)
            {
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
            if (!success)
            {
                glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
};
#endif
```

My vertex and fragment shader are very basic, so I don't know if these are the reasons for my weird output, but here it is.

DVDVertexShader.txt :

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

DVDFragmentShader.txt :

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;


void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord);
}
```

Anyway, I really think the shader isn't really the problem. The image "dvd_logo2.png" is this one.

[dvd_logo2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIfWW.png)
However, the output I get from my code is this.
[weird_dvd_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGA0L.png)
(My original intention was to make the output have the same look as the input so I could do sth to it afterwards like make it move around per frame.)

I don't understand why this is happening... The funny thing is, other images with all kinds of colors work perfectly fine. Maybe the problem is because the photo's black and white..?

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You never check `nrChannels` and pass `0` as `desired_channels` to `stbi_load`.

Comment: I checked nrChannels right now, and it turns out it's 2. And the other color image I got had nrChannels = 3. But does this make a difference..?

Comment: You pass `GL_RGB` to `glTexImage2D`, so it expects three components, you got only two. As your resulting screenshot shows, this does make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's `*.png` you need change at last `format` to `GL_RGBA` and by `format` I don't mean `internalFormat`, so something like that should work `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);`. For what I mean by `format` and `internalFormat` check reference: [glTexImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)

If you still can't understand why it is then let me make quote from that reference:

> format
>
> ```
> Specifies the format of the pixel data.
> ```

So your pixel data have GL_RGBA value: red, green, blue, and alpha since it's *.png, problem is that now you pass only 3 of them.

EDIT:

I don't note it first time but you need also change in stbi_load number of components to 4:

```
stbi_load("dvd_logo2.png", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 4);
```

Comment: changing format to GL_RGBA gives me a runtime error : (

Comment: try change stbi to stbi_load("dvd_logo2.png", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 4); With 0 I also get runtime error.

Comment: your answer helped me a lot! thank you. quick question though.. in the tutorials, even when the texture input was a jpg file(which meant I had to change format as GL_RGB), we had stdi_load number of components as 0. Why didn't we change it as 3, but kept it as 0? and why did it still work that way?

Comment: I think it's not proper to explain such thing in comment. Best thing for you will be check for more details comments in stb_image.h -> around 131 line. You have there explained all arguments that "stbi_load" take. Or you can make another question :>. Basically last argument if non-zero enforce components, otherwise thing that go to nrChannels automatically detect